# Fetch Lists Attribute in Subscriber Object Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

Looking at the [Subscriber Object docs](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/subscriber/), I see that a "Lists" attribute is offered as an attribute that can be requested.  However, whenever I include it in my query, I get an error like this:

```
Error: The Request Property(s) Lists do not match with the fields of Subscriber retrieve
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say query, what do you mean?  A query activity?  Something else? Please post.

Comment: @Timothy RetrieveRequest.  [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/jarcoal/71fd0ec1e4dd5f96234f)  with an example.

Comment: I was trying to do the same now and came across this post. In the docs it shows the Lists array accessible from the Subscriber object similar to attributes. I can get attributes but not Lists. Was it determined the only way to do this is two separate requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to retrieve all of the Lists a Subscriber is on.

You do this by retrieving the SubscriberList object. It will return ListID of any lists they are on. Unfortunately if you want more information about the list you need to then retrieve the List object using that ListID.

Here is an example:

```
<ns1:Body>
  <ns0:RetrieveRequestMsg>
    <ns0:RetrieveRequest>
      <ns0:ObjectType>SubscriberList</ns0:ObjectType>
      <ns0:Properties>Status</ns0:Properties>
      <ns0:Properties>ID</ns0:Properties>
      <ns0:Properties>SubscriberKey</ns0:Properties>
      <ns0:Filter xsi:type="ns0:SimpleFilterPart">
        <ns0:Property>SubscriberKey</ns0:Property>
        <ns0:SimpleOperator>equals</ns0:SimpleOperator>
        <ns0:Value>test@gmail.com</ns0:Value>
      </ns0:Filter>
    </ns0:RetrieveRequest>
  </ns0:RetrieveRequestMsg>
</ns1:Body>
```

Its also documented [here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_all_lists_a_subscriber_is_on/).